# MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, graphql, mongodb-atlas

Hi I am making a booking system following the youtube tutorial [tutorial link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MRrcUQhZwBc&list=PL55RiY5tL51rG1x02Yyj93iypUuHYXcB_&index=8)

And I have made app.js file to be like(shown below):

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const { graphqlHTTP } = require('express-graphql');
const { buildSchema } = require('graphql');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const User = require('./models/user')

const Event = require('./models/events');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(
    '/graphql',
    graphqlHTTP({
        schema: buildSchema(`
        type Event {
          _id: ID!
          title: String!
          description: String!
          price: Float!
          date: String!
        }
        type User {
            _id: ID!
            username: String!
            studentnumber: String
        }
        input EventInput {
          title: String!
          description: String!
          price: Float!
          date: String!
        }
        type UserInput {
            username: String!
            studentnumber: String!
        }
        type RootQuery {
            events: [Event!]!
        }
        type RootMutation {
            createEvent(eventInput: EventInput): Event
            createUser(userInput: UserInput): User
        }
        schema {
            query: RootQuery
            mutation: RootMutation
        }
    `),
        rootValue: {
            events: () => {
                return Event.find()
                    .then(events => {
                        return events.map(event => {
                            return { ...event._doc, _id: event.id };
                        });
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        throw err;
                    });
            },
            createEvent: args => {
                const event = new Event({
                    title: args.eventInput.title,
                    description: args.eventInput.description,
                    price: +args.eventInput.price,
                    date: new Date(args.eventInput.date)
                });
                return event
                    .save()
                    .then(result => {
                        console.log(result);
                        return { ...result._doc, _id: result._doc._id.toString() };
                    })
                    .catch(err => {
                        console.log(err);
                        throw err;
                    });
            },
        },
        graphiql: true
    })
);

mongoose
    .connect(
        `mongodb+srv://${process.env.MONGO_USER}:${process.env.MONGO_PASSWORD}@cluster0.scgam.mongodb.net/${process.env.MONGO_DB}?retryWrites=true&w=majority`
    )
    .then(() => {
        app.listen(3002);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    });
```

But this gives this error message:

```
[nodemon] 2.0.15
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
MongooseServerSelectionError: Could not connect to any servers in your MongoDB Atlas cluster. One common reason is that you're trying to access the data
base from an IP that isn't whitelisted. Make sure your current IP address is on your Atlas cluster's IP whitelist: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/securi
ty-whitelist/
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Documents\GitHub\2021-StudySkillsApp\Bookings\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:8
07:32)
    at C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Documents\GitHub\2021-StudySkillsApp\Bookings\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:342:10
    at C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Documents\GitHub\2021-StudySkillsApp\Bookings\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Documents\GitHub\2021-StudySkillsApp\Bookings\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:1
0)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Documents\GitHub\2021-StudySkillsApp\Bookings\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1181:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Documents\GitHub\2021-StudySkillsApp\Bookings\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:341:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Abdulrahman\Documents\GitHub\2021-StudySkillsApp\Bookings\app.js:89:6)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
    servers: Map(3) {
      'cluster0-shard-00-00.scgam.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-01.scgam.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
      'cluster0-shard-00-02.scgam.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
    },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    setName: 'atlas-jlm5p9-shard-0',
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
  },
  code: undefined
}
[nodemon] clean exit - waiting for changes before restart
```

And I am sure I put my home IP as the IP's I can connect to and have made the username+password+dbname correct (they're in the nodemon.json file which I call by process.env.variablename) and that the URL linked works

Also this is what I get when searching localhost:3002/graphql if it helps
[image: search result]
Any help would be nice as I need it to work thanks :)

Comment: Title should have had in your MongoDB Atlas cluster but didn't allow me so I put it here in case it helps

Answer (score 0):

The IP address seen by Atlas is not necessarily the IP address of your workstations. If behind a router that does NAT or using VPN the address seen is the one of the router or the exit point of the VPN.

First try to Allow Access From Anywhere. If it works it is most likely because you whitelisted an IP address that is not your public address. Find your public IP with https://www.whatismyip.com/

If the above does not work then we need more information to help.